# Problems with video and playback on 4K monitor and R9 R270 AMD. Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, video, flash, amd-graphics

For a number of years I have happily used Ubuntu. However, I am having all sorts of problems now since I upgraded my video card and monitor. My monitor is a Benq 4k monitor, but I decided to upgrade my video card to a AMD R9 270.

I have installed the latest drivers from AMD, fglrx. This is when my problems started as follows:

1. I can no longer play flash in firefox, the Adobe Flash plugin keeps crashing.
2. Playing Youtube videos at full screen is like watching a slideshow, really slow, it seems like there is no hardware acceleration. Flash or HTML5 both are slow.
3. I tried switching to Chrome as a workaround for the flash issue, which worked fine at the start, but now Chrome is unusable as all it does its keep flickering on my desktop when I start it up.

Is this all fixable? Or is a combination of 4k, AMD etc unusable on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up upgrading and re-installing Ubuntu 14.10. As soon as I did this the video acceleration in YouTube and Flash worked a treat. I have now upgraded further to 15.04, and this version also works well for video playback on 4K.

My recommendation based on my experience is that you should install the AMD Proprietary drivers as doing this caused me all sorts of problems. It is not straightforward removing these drivers and getting your system back to a working condition either.

Comment: Not sure why you are installing and using unsupported version of Ubuntu. Is there any reason why you did install 16.04 instead (16.04 is an LTS - Long Term Support)?

Comment: @VanessaDeagan probably because 16.04 was not available in 2015 :-))